# CentOs 6.3 External monitor

Tags: centos

I am having problems make my external monitor work under the centOs 6.3 using nvidia graphic card. Also I install the nvidia driver but when I rebooted my system it didn't open the X driver so I had to rename the xorg.conf file. Any suggestions step by step in order to make my external monitor work? Keep in mind that I am really new in centOS. Thank you in advance.